# How to insert a Controller in Twig with “render” in Silex

Tags: php, twig, silex

Should it work in Silex with symfony/twig-bridge ?

```
{{ render(controller('MyController')) }}
```

Now I have message like this:

> Twig_Error_Syntax: The function "controller" does not exist in "...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found this working:

```
{{ render(controller('services.controller:action', {[params]}) }}
```

And you can define the controller as a service:

```
$app['services.controller'] = function() use ($dependecy1, .., $dependencyN){
    return new \\PathToYourControllerClass($dependecy1, .., $dependencyN);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use it this way:

```
{{ render(path('your_route_id', {'id': id, 'anotherParam': param})) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found this working :

```
{{ render(controller('Full\\Namespace\\To\\Your\\Controller::listAction')) }}
```

please don't forget a double slash '\\'

Example:

```
{{ render(controller('Acme\\ProductController::listAction')) }}
```

In Your ProductController (I'm using Doctrine 2 in this example) :

```
public function listAction(Application $application)
{
    $em = $application['orm.em'];

    $produits = $em->getRepository('Acme\Entity\Produit')->findAll();

    return $application['twig']->render('list.html.twig', array(
        'products' => $products
    ));
}
```

Then in your list.html.twig

```
{% for product in products %}
  <h2> {{ product.name }} </h2>
{% endfor %}
```