# Silex php dynamic menu

Tags: php, symfony, menu, silex

I'm new to Silex and PHP frameworks in general and I'm trying to make a blog in order to train myself.

Currently I want to create a system that can handle pages, so in a backoffice the admin will be able to modify/create pages.

My problem is with the menu (nav bar) I'm not sure how I am supposed to do it. It has it has to be dynamic - e.g. if the admin creates a new page called *what about us* then in the menu there will be a link to that page.

Also here is my layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <title>Blog - Silex</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ app.request.getBaseUrl() }}/web/css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arima+Madurai|Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Silex Tp</h1>

            {% include "nav.twig" %}

            {% block body %}{% endblock body %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

So I'm not sure what to write in the *nav.twig* file.

I tried to find information but the only things I can find are about Symfony.

Comment: You can do it by multiple way. I don't know your backend architecture, but you can do a middleware who get your pages in the database and then store them in a global variable (like $app etc.).

Comment: well, I tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417672/how-to-insert-a-controller-in-twig-with-render-in-silex but it's not working because i'm not sure what to put in params so I tried the middleware and it works, but is it a good solution ? Because I feel like it's a little bit messy ? Thank you

Comment: The [KnpMenu](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenu) library can help you managing the menus, if you connect it to the dabatase to generate the menus based on the system pages you'll get the expected result.

Comment: I think the render() is also a good solution. In his example `dependencyN` can be $app, $request, or whatever variable you need.

Comment: Ok but what should I put for this line: {{ render(controller('services.controller:action', {[params]}) }} ?